# error in my linux terminal with rvm

Tags: ruby, linux, bash, terminal, rvm

Whats does this error mean? its occuring my the terminal on my ubuntu VM

```
bash: /home/greg/.bashrc: line 110: conditional binary operator expected
bash: /home/greg/.bashrc: line 110: syntax error near `"$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"'
bash: /home/greg/.bashrc: line 110: `[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"]] && source $HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need a space here, right before the `]]`:

```
`[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"]]
```

As in:

```
`[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]]
```

Comment: @Greg Edit in `~/.bashrc` and reload it using `source ~/.bashrc`

Comment: im new to linux where can i do this?

Comment: @Greg: Open a terminal window, type `gedit ~/.bashrc`, then go to line 110 and add the space in.

Comment: Go to your home directory and press `Cntrl+h` it will show hidden files. Then open `.bashrc` edit and save.

Comment: @sampson-chen it will not always at 110 line. It depends what u have in that file.

Comment: I think double quote is missing before `$HOME` of source: it should be `[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"`

Comment: it was the space and it was at at very end of file